# Coverting byte[] from stereo to mono produces crackling in OpenAL

Tags: c#, .net, openal

I'm trying to convert a Stereo byte[] to mono byte[]

Here is my code :

```
    private byte[] ToMono(byte[] data)
    {
        byte[] newData = new byte[data.Length / 2];

        for(int i = 0; i < data.Length / 4; ++i)
        {
            int HI = 1; int LO = 0;
            int left = (data[i * 4 + HI] << 8) | (data[i * 4 + LO] & 0xff);
            int right = (data[i * 4 + 2 + HI] << 8) | (data[i * 4 + 2 + LO] & 0xff);
            int avg = ((right + left) / 2);

            newData[i * 2 + HI] = (byte)((avg >> 8) & 0xff);
            newData[i * 2 + LO] = (byte)((avg & 0xff));
        }
        return newData;
    }
```

It converts to mono alright, but It produces crackling in OpenAL.

It seems that if I compile with "int avg = left;" The crackling stops. But I wanted to mix down both channels.

What is wrong with my code? How can take out the crackling?

Answer (score 1):

so for anybody struggling with stereo to mono conversion (16 bit pcm stereo) Here go's a solution:

```
    private byte[] ToMono(byte[] data)
    {
        byte[] newData = new byte[data.Length / 2];

        for(int i = 0; i < data.Length / 4; ++i)
        {
            int HI = 1; int LO = 0;
            short left = (short)((data[i * 4 + HI] << 8) | (data[i * 4 + LO] & 0xff));
            short right = (short)((data[i * 4 + 2 + HI] << 8) | (data[i * 4 + 2 + LO] & 0xff));
            int avg = (left + right) / 2;

            newData[i * 2 + HI] = (byte)((avg >> 8) & 0xff);
            newData[i * 2 + LO] = (byte)((avg & 0xff));
        }

        return newData;
    }
```

Comment: What was the issue, and what is the fix? This will help users to avoid comparing both code snippets and missing subtleties.

Comment: setting left and right channels to short instead of int